# How to use %debug to investigate Python unittest failure?

Tags: python, unit-testing, ipython

How can I run a single Python [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html) from within IPython and use `%debug` to investigate the site of an assertion failure?

Specifically, I want this magic...

```
$ ipython
In [1]: def broken():
   ...:     DOESNOTEXIST
   ...:    

In [2]: broken()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-38dbcef999e4> in <module>()
----> 1 broken()

<ipython-input-1-42074db4a06b> in broken()
      1 def broken():
----> 2     DOESNOTEXIST
      3 

NameError: name 'DOESNOTEXIST' is not defined

In [3]: %debug
> <ipython-input-1-42074db4a06b>(2)broken()
      1 def broken():
----> 2     DOESNOTEXIST
      3 

ipdb> # Rock on
```

...available when kicking off unittest...

```
In [4]: %run -m unittest some/path/to/brokenness.py
```

...where, on failure, running `%debug` would take me to the `raise` that failed some test case.

Seems the [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html) module swallows the exceptions (as one would expect) and the `--failfast` flag won't cough them up.  I know I can instantiate the test object and then invoke `setUp()`, etc. manually on it.  But that seems mildly silly and a pain.  I don't want to set breakpoints.

Comment: I'd happily also take a solution where I can get dropped into IPython only on failure.

Comment: More happily in fact.  Would be nice to simply run from the CLI and get an IPython-friendly debugger on the tripped assertion.

Comment: You can run tests in ipython using `nose`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a testrunner

I recommend you to install [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) with pytest-ipdb plugin. You should be able to run it in a similar way with --ipdb flag to get to the ipdb debugger when an exception happens in your test.

```
pip install git+git://github.com/mverteuil/pytest-ipdb.git
```

Then

```
In [1]: %run -m pytest --ipdb some/path/to/brokenness.py
```

or from the command line:

```
py.test --ipdb some/path/to/brokenness.py
```

Also, if you don't like pytest for some reason, the same result can be archived with nose and [nose-ipdb](https://github.com/flavioamieiro/nose-ipdb) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a running [`nose`](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).  This can run separately via commandline, within ipython or jupyter notebook.

```
> pip install nose
```

In the package directory containing the test files, run:

```
> nosetests --pdb
```

This will automatically find test modules prepended `test_` in all present and sub-directories.  Alternatively, you can run it on separate files:

```
> nosetests test_filename.py --pdb
```

There is a [plugin](https://github.com/flavioamieiro/nose-ipdb) to use `ipdb` as well.

`nose` is particularly useful for running tests inside a ipython/jupyter session.  Therefore, you have the option to run tests inside a session without making separate files:

```
import nose.tools as nt

def test():
    # Some test code
    return 1

nt.assert_equal(test(), 2)
```

Output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-edbfc78f9c45> in <module>()
      5     return 1
      6 
----> 7 nt.assert_equal(test(), 2)

C:\Anaconda3\envs\betalab\lib\unittest\case.py in assertEqual(self, first, second, msg)
    818         """
    819         assertion_func = self._getAssertEqualityFunc(first, second)
--> 820         assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
    821 
    822     def assertNotEqual(self, first, second, msg=None):

C:\Anaconda3\envs\betalab\lib\unittest\case.py in _baseAssertEqual(self, first, second, msg)
    811             standardMsg = '%s != %s' % _common_shorten_repr(first, second)
    812             msg = self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg)
--> 813             raise self.failureException(msg)
    814 
    815     def assertEqual(self, first, second, msg=None):

AssertionError: 1 != 2
```

Comment: From the nose documentation: "Nose has been in maintenance mode for the past several years and will likely cease without a new person/team to take over maintainership. New projects should consider using Nose2, py.test, or just plain unittest/unittest2."

Comment: It works just fine for unittests.  You can try `nose2` if you'd like.   `pytest` would be the best, but it does not yet support session testing.